# Automatic ActiveJDBC instrumentation in VSCode

Tags: java, maven, activejdbc

I use VSCode as editor and I need to make automatic running instrumentation of my model classes.
To run it manually I run in shell `mvn org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:2.0:instrument`

Answer (score 2):

I use following VSCode extension to develop on Java: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

solved:
1. create `.vscode/tasks.json`

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "Run instrumentation",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "mvn org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:2.0:instrument"
      }
  ]
}
```

2. add `"preLaunchTask": "Run instrumentation"` in `.vscode/launch.json`

Comment: can this be automatically run somehow with `mvn compile`